# Eagerly loading and injecting tab contents in Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want eagerly loaded contents to be injected to the DOM immediately, not until the tab is activated in Angular Material. This is how the documentation mentions the default behavior.

> By default, the tab contents are eagerly loaded. Eagerly loaded tabs will initalize the child components but not inject them into the DOM until the tab is activated.

As it says `but not inject them into the DOM`, I want to do the opposite and inject them. Is there any possible ways of doing it?

Comment: were you able to get this figured out? I have the same question!

Comment: unfortunately, no.

Comment: For what it is worth, I have this problem too and need a solution, sadly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force Mat Tab body to render/bind html element for inactive tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129174/how-to-force-mat-tab-body-to-render-bind-html-element-for-inactive-tab)