# How to force Mat Tab body to render/bind html element for inactive tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular mat-tab-group
How do i force angular to bind html element of inactive tabs, below is the html implementation

```
<mat-tab label="Test">
    <app-test></app-test>
</mat-tab>
```

the test.component.ts file did initialize and run, but the html element is not binded, view attached image below. is there a way to force angular to bind it? i'm intergrating some 3rd party libary that requires the html element to be binded when the component.ts files start executing or else it will break.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can not, you can use the events (selectedTabChange) or (selectedIndexChange). NOTE: If you see the API about [TabMatGroup](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup) in @Output you has all the "events" you can "reach", you allways use, e.g. `(selectedTabChange)="yourFunction($event)"` and the argument of the function is the indicate in the API under "EmitterEvent" -in this case is of type `MatTabChangeEvent`-

Exist another option that is create a tabgroup without content, and use a variable index

```
//in your .ts
index=0
```

Then you create an .html like

```html
    <!-- see that you use margin-bottom and animationDuration -->
    <mat-tab-group style="margin-bottom:5px;" animationDuration="0" 
               mat-align-tabs="start" (selectedIndexChange)="index=$event">
    <!-- you makes the mat-tabs "empty" -->
      <mat-tab label="First"></mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Second"></mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Third"></mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
    <!--here you put your content using [style.display]="none" when 
        the index is not equal to hte value (remember index begings by 0-->
    <div [style.display]="index!=0?'none':null">
      Content 1
    </div>
    <div [style.display]="index!=1?'none':null">
    Content 2
    </div>
    <div [style.display]="index!=2?'none':null">
    Content 3
    </div>
```

But you need create the "animation" manually. For this you can add the animation to your component

```
  animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
      transition(':decrement', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
        animate(200)
      ]),
      transition(':increment', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
        animate(200)
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

And use an auxiliar variable "indexOld". Then use the animation in the html

```
<mat-tab-group style="margin-bottom:5px;" animationDuration="0" 
     mat-align-tabs="start" (selectedIndexChange)="index=$event">
  <mat-tab label="First"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<!--see that now I use "indexOld", not "index"
    when the animation is done, you equal indexOld to index-->

<div [style.display]="indexOld!=0?'none':null" [@flyInOut]="index" (@flyInOut.done)="indexOld=index">
  Content 1
</div>
<div [style.display]="indexOld!=1?'none':null" [@flyInOut]="index" (@flyInOut.done)="indexOld=index">
Content 2
</div>
<div [style.display]="indexOld!=2?'none':null" [@flyInOut]="index" (@flyInOut.done)="indexOld=index">
Content 3
</div>
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsqjhj?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-align-example.html)

NOTE: Really it's not "exact" to the animation in mat-tab, fell free to change the animations to make it more closer

**Update** a animation that "simulate" the animation of a mat-tab

we need see two "tabs" at time, so we need "wrapper" the tabs in a div with position relative and makes position absolute. This makes we need know the "height" of the tabs. So we are going to use "visibility" instead of "display", but first we are going to defined four animations

```
  animations: [
    trigger('flyInOut', [
      transition('*=>inmore', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }), //start in
        animate(200)
      ]),
      transition('*=>inless', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }), //start in
        animate(200)
      ]),
      transition('*=>outless', [
        animate(200, style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' })) //end in
      ]),
      transition('*=>outmore', [
        animate(200, style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })) //end in
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

We are going to see the tab if is "i" is index or indexOld and to get the "animation" we are going to use a function

```
  getAnimation(i:number,indexOld:number,index:number)
  {
    const from=(i==index)?'in':(i==indexOld)?'out':null
    if (from && indexOld!=index)
        return from+(indexOld>index?'less':'more')
    return null
  }
```

And the .html like

```
<div class="wrapper" [style.height]="maxHeigth">
  <div #tab [style.visibility]="index!=0 && indexOld!=0?'hidden':null" [@flyInOut]="getAnimation(0,indexOld,index)"
    (@flyInOut.done)="indexOld=index">
    Content 1
  </div>
  <div #tab [style.visibility]="index!=1 && indexOld!=1?'hidden':null" [@flyInOut]="getAnimation(1,indexOld,index)"
    (@flyInOut.done)="indexOld=index">
    Content 2
  </div>
  <div #tab [style.visibility]="index!=2 && indexOld!=2?'hidden':null" [@flyInOut]="getAnimation(2,indexOld,index)"
    (@flyInOut.done)="indexOld=index">
    Content 3
  </div>
</div>
```

See that the wrapper class indicate

```
.wrapper
{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
.wrapper>div
{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```

The last step is know the "maxHeigth", so, we are going to get the "tabs" using viewChildren and, in ngAfterViewInit enclosed in setTimeout, get the maxHeigth

```
  maxHeigth:string;
  @ViewChildren('tab') tabs:QueryList<ElementRef>

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
    this.maxHeigth=this.tabs.map(x=>x.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height)
                 .reduce((a,b)=>a>b?a:b,0)+'px'
    })
  }
```

You can see the [final stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbqbyo?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-align-example.ts)

Comment: Great answer! Too bad that there isn't an option to eager load the content of all tabs :(

Comment: @CaioCampos, see that the "tabs" really are only divs. You can use a loop to create the divs and load whatever inside. Well, you need calculate maxHeight after the divs are fully loaded.

Comment: my main issue was that I needed all the content to be rendered, even though the tab had never been activated yet. I thought that `preserveContent` would do that, but instead it just "doesn't remove" the content after it's been rendered once, which was not good enough in my case, where I have a "Next Issue" button that navigates through invalid fields on all tabs. Your answer solved my problem. Thanks.