# Angular material tabs - responsive tab change

Tags: angular, angular-material

i have two tabs inside mat-tab-group:

```
<mat-tab-group
  animationDuration="0ms"
  [disablePagination]="false"
  mat-stretch-tabs="false"
  mat-align-tabs="start"
>
  <mat-tab label="First tab">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-first-tab />
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="Second tab">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-second-tab />
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

On the first tab I generate a lot of components, so it take some time till it is fully rendered.
When I select second tab and go back to first tab, app freezes (for couple of seconds) till all is rendered.
Would it be possible to show eg. header (its more-less static), some spinner, and when everything is rendered, hide the spinner? Or let user somehow know that something is happening?

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sb2saw .. just for testing purposes.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A mat-tab use `*ngIf` to show a tab. You can use some like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129174/how-to-force-mat-tab-body-to-render-bind-html-element-for-inactive-tab/68129729#68129729) that use a mat-tab and divs that use `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're experiencing has two pieces:

1. The simulation of your async request is actually using a synchronous function (for loop), which is being run when the service is accessed. This is not how a standard Observable would work in the wild, and is also where the very long waits between tabs originates.
2. You can utilize a container and template to display a loading spinner while your async variable is loading.

Example HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data; else loading">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Buttons</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.code }}</td>
        <td>
          @for (idx of buttonCount; track idx; let index = $index) {
          <button>{{ idx }}</button>
          }
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading><mat-spinner></mat-spinner></ng-template>
```

Updated Service to better simulate async data (which could also be shared as Observable):

```
  async fetchData(): Promise<ApiModel[]> {
    let result: ApiModel[] = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.cnt; i++) {
      result.push({ id: i, code: `item_${i}` });
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(result), Math.random() * 5000);
    });
  }
```

The result is instantly swapped tabs, which show a spinner icon while data is being loaded:

[image]

[StackBlitz Link of Fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cjcjgy?file=src%2Ffirst-tab%2Ffirst-tab.component.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. But I do not think, that problem is loading of data. Problem is, that I need to show a lot of controls on the form, an this operation takes much more time than loading.
I modified the example, and let say, that the data is stored in the cache, so the condition  "<ng-container *ngIf="data; else loading">" is useless, because the data is available immediately. But tab is changed when all controls are rendered/destroyed. Till that app seems to be "frozen".
Of course i do not generate thousand of buttons in real app, but I wanted to emphasize the core of the problem.

Comment: Updated example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mdzrzp

Comment: II see, so the issue really is the synchronous issue - which means the Observable/async is irrelevant. The `for` loop is the core of the issue in your stackblitz, this is a synchronous function that must complete completely before the thread is released (and the UI can re-render). More of a fundamental javascript issue is shown rather than anything Angular specific. An example to turn it into an async function can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of - this is where you could then utilize similar functions as in my answer.